# Error uploading using aws s3 mb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cron

Im trying to make my ec2 upload files on startup to my s3 bucket using crontab. I used the following lines in *crontab -e*

```
@rebbot > s3log
@reboot aws s3 cp /path/localfile.csv s3://bucketname >> s3log 2>&1
```

The first line clears the log file, and the second make the upload and logs it on a file named 's3log'. After this everything that appears on the s3log is:

> upload: ./data_xxxxxxx.csv to s3://bucket-name/data_xxxxxxx.csv

So far everything ok, the file was meaning to move is on the ec2

[image: file]

But when i try to access the file from the s3 bucket it has nothing on it

[image: 0Kb file on S3]

The file is empty. Any ideas why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never find out what was the problem but i finally worked around it using boto3 in my python script to upload the file. This way the crontab only has to run the script on startup and thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [aws mb](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/mb.html) docs.  They are really just for making a bucket, not uploading.  Based on what you're showing I would expect something more like:

```
@rebbot > s3log
@reboot aws s3 mb s3://bucketname >> s3log 2>&1
@reboot aws cp /path/localfile.csv s3://bucketname >> s3log 2>&1
```

Comment: I was actually using 'cp' i just tipped it wrong. And im using an already created buecket.

Comment: If you run this from the command line - without using cron - does it work then?

Comment: yes it works when i do it manually but its supposed to be a daily task